# Can I delete "while doing so" in this sentence？

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, sentence-meaning

"Worse, should you attempt to diet but don’t get enough sleep **while doing so**, it is futile, since most of the weight you lose will come from lean body mass, not fat."
what function or meaning does it in the sentence？

Comment: The inclusion of _while doing so_ makes it clear that it's doing those things _at the same time_ which causes the unwanted effect.

Comment: @KateBunting，can I use "at the same time" or "meanwhile" to replace "while doing so"？

Comment: "While doing so" is a temporal adjunct in clause structure. "Doing so" is complement of "while" and serves as a kind of 'pro-VP' with "attempt to diet" as antecedent. It's interpreted as "Worse, should you attempt to diet but don’t get enough sleep while attempting to diet" ...   Deleting "while doing so" would diminish the concurrent sense of "don't get enough sleep", which causes the futility.

Comment: I don’t think “but don’t get” properly parallels “should you attempt”.  I think “should you attempt to diet, but fail to get enough sleep” works better.

Comment: @BillJ  I feel you get it right though I can't feel that subtle sense.

Comment: @Jim I think it is an emphasizing to better convey that you should not diet while not enough sleep. it is not important when deleted.

Comment: @cenwun - No it’s a matter of sentence structure being inconsistent.